# Redirect text file created with PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that create a text file using the file_put_contents() function. It goes simply like this:

```
$mytext = "sample text";
file_put_contents('my_new_file.txt', $mytext);
```

The issue is that I would like the file to be downloaded by the user Download folder and not the website Root folder.

So my question is: **How to send the newly created text file to the user computer?**

Comment: You would use a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the file, then use [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect the user.

```
<?php
$mytext = "sample text";
file_put_contents('my_new_file.txt', $mytext);
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Location: my_new_file.txt");
?>
```

Comment: Add this before the last header in the answer: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_new_file.txt"');`